# How do I redirect between TLDs when using a HTTPS connection in node?

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, https

Using node.js and express.js. I have the following problem:

I want to redirect all the traffic from *mydomain.se* to *mydomain.com*. This seems like a fairly easy task and a solution could possibly be:

```
app.get('*/', function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.headers && req.headers.host && req.headers.host.indexOf('.se') > 0)
        res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host.replace('.se', '.com') + req.url);
}
```

The problem however is that I am using HTTPS and that I've only purchased a legit SSL certificate for the .com domain. This means that when I enter *mydomain.se* I will first see the "Your connection is not private" warning message, and when I've pressed the "Proceed to mydomain.se (unsafe)" button, then I get redirected to .com.

Is it possible to perform the redirect before the SSL warning is shown?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible if you want your certificate to be valid.

Depending on you Certificate Authority, you could probably add mydomain.se to the SubjectAltName extension of your certificate for free.

If you can't, I'm afraid there is no other way to buy a new one...